# How do I look at just the reviews of the format I'm buying on Amazon

Tags: amazon, kindle

I just bought a Kindle but when I look at reviews of a Kindle book I see reviews of the paperback and hardbacks.

How do I filter the reviews so I just see reviews specifically of the Kindle copy?

This would also apply to VCR/DVD/Blu-ray reviews.

Comment: Why did you add that tag back? [We're trying to get rid of the `review` tag](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/for-your-reviews?cb=1).

Comment: Further, we're also [trying to get rid of the 'filter' tag](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/lets-clean-up-some-meta-tags).

Comment: Please stop deleting useful tagzs. Don't be that guy who cleans everything so pure it's not useful.

Comment: How are those tags useful?

Comment: It's about searching to be able to focus on the Q&A that applies to one's particular problem. The more specificity in the tags, the more targeted the list you can get from searching. That saves time, therefore it's useful. Remember this is a site about Web Apps, and some of those apps are for the purpose of reviews, or reviews are a major part of what they do. It wouldn't be a good tag for SO or SU, but it is here. Note though that I messed up and it should have been 'reviews' as it was, but now I can't change it.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to participate in the conversations on [meta] about tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the reply I received when I asked Amazon this question:

> Different editions, bindings, or
>   versions of a title are often linked
>   in our system so customers can easily
>   find the version they're looking for.
>   In such cases, the same reviews appear
>   on the product detail pages for all
>   versions.
>
> Such content sharing allows us to
>   provide all review information
>   possible, regardless of the edition.
>   This includes both editorial reviews
>   and customer reviews.
>
> I'm sorry, but there is not a way to
>   filter these kinds of reviews.

Comment: I hate this, and want to downvote it so bad  but it's the official answer. Shame on Amazon. Terrible web developers and product managers.